# Upgrading to Expo 50 can´t build iOS

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo

I am trying to upgrade Expo SDK from 49 to 50, but I can't make the ios app run. https://expo.dev/changelog/2024/01-18-sdk-50

pods install runs without errors.

When I run npx expo run:ios I get:

```
❌  (ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Dmaze/ExpoModulesProvider.swift:8:8)

   6 |  */
   7 | 
>  8 | import ExpoModulesCore
     |        ^ compiling for iOS 13.0, but module 'ExpoModulesCore' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.4: /Users/marvin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dmaze-eherjphdqufazvbjufezzvmfviqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExpoModulesCore/ExpoModulesCore.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
   9 | import EXConstants
  10 | import ExpoFileSystem
  11 | import ExpoKeepAwake


❌  (ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Dmaze/ExpoModulesProvider.swift:8:8)

   6 |  */
   7 | 
>  8 | import ExpoModulesCore
     |        ^ compiling for iOS 13.0, but module 'ExpoModulesCore' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.4: /Users/marvin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dmaze-eherjphdqufazvbjufezzvmfviqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExpoModulesCore/ExpoModulesCore.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
   9 | import EXConstants
  10 | import ExpoFileSystem
  11 | import ExpoKeepAwake


❌  (ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Dmaze/ExpoModulesProvider.swift:8:8)

   6 |  */
   7 | 
>  8 | import ExpoModulesCore
     |        ^ compiling for iOS 13.0, but module 'ExpoModulesCore' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.4: /Users/marvin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dmaze-eherjphdqufazvbjufezzvmfviqj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExpoModulesCore/ExpoModulesCore.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
   9 | import EXConstants
  10 | import ExpoFileSystem
  11 | import ExpoKeepAwake


› 3 error(s), and 0 warning(s)

CommandError: Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.
```

I set the target to 13.4 in the Podfile:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")

require 'json'
pod 'AppAuth'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = podfile_properties['newArchEnabled'] == 'true' ? '1' : '0'
ENV['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR'] = podfile_properties['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR']

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.4'
```

Why is it compiling for iOS 13.0? How can I make it build for 13.4?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

**Update Deployment Target in Xcode:** Besides setting the deployment target in the Podfile, you also need to ensure that the deployment target is set correctly in Xcode for your project and all its targets. Open your project in Xcode, select the project file in the navigator, then for each target (including the main app target and any test targets), go to the General tab and set the Deployment Target to iOS 13.4 or higher.

Comment: I face same issue, and I notice that update target is because the library not the supported version, you should install all library based on recommendation version, use npx expo install --check, install the correct version will remove all the warning, I don't need to add expo build properties again.

Comment: I just clear out my pre-build and it started working again

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error with Expo 49 and expo EAS build. Is there any way I can fix it without ejecting from expo?

❌  (ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Storage.swift:73:12)

71 |     let provider = ComponentType.instance(for: StorageProvider.self,
72 |                                                            in: app.container)

> 73 |     return provider.storage(for: Storage.bucket(for: app))
> |            ^ value of optional type '?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'storage' of wrapped base type 'any StorageProvider'
> 74 |   }
> 75 |
> 76 |   /**

❌  (ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Storage.swift:88:12)

86 |     let provider = ComponentType.instance(for: StorageProvider.self,
87 |                                                            in: app.container)

> 88 |     return provider.storage(for: Storage.bucket(for: app, urlString: url))
> |            ^ value of optional type '?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'storage' of wrapped base type 'any StorageProvider'
> 89 |   }
> 90 |
> 91 |   /**

❌  (ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Storage.swift:291:39)

289 |   init(app: FirebaseApp, bucket: String) {
290 |     self.app = app

> 291 |     auth = ComponentType.instance(for: AuthInterop.self,
> |                                       ^ cannot assign value of type '?' to type 'any AuthInterop'
> 292 |                                                in: app.container)
> 293 |     appCheck = ComponentType.instance(for: AppCheckInterop.self,
> 294 |                                                        in: app.container)

❌  (ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Storage.swift:293:47)

291 |     auth = ComponentType.instance(for: AuthInterop.self,
292 |                                                in: app.container)

> 293 |     appCheck = ComponentType.instance(for: AppCheckInterop.self,
> |                                               ^ cannot assign value of type '?' to type 'any AppCheckInterop'
> 294 |                                                        in: app.container)
> 295 |     storageBucket = bucket
> 296 |     host = "firebasestorage.googleapis.com"

If you have any suggestions, that would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).